# How to make a 'str' object callable using lambda functions?

Tags: python, string, lambda

I have some predefined functions with me, like :
addhost, edithost, deletehost.

Now based on some param received, I have to call one of the above functions.
Now the value of param is same as one of the above functions.The type of param is str.

**For Example:** If param is 'addhost', then I should be able  to call addhost().
But when I do it directly, It gives me the error as `'str' object is not callable`
How should I call the appropriate function based on param received ??

**P.S.** I dont want to use conditionals, I only want to go with something like lambda functions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling a function from a string with the function's name in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-from-a-string-with-the-functions-name-in-python)

Comment: This is a bad idea; put your functions in a dictionary keyed with the strings you want to use to access them.

Comment: *Where/how* is this function defined? In a module? A function within the current scope? A method? (The linked question seems to cover most cases..)

Comment: str='os.unlink("this program")'

Answer (score 1):

Simple call `eval`:

```
>>> def addhost():
...  print "Add host"
... 
>>> def edithost():
...  print "Edit host"
... 
>>> def callstr(str):
...  f = eval(str)
...  f()
... 
>>> callstr("addhost")
Add host
>>> callstr("edithost")
Edit host
>>>
```

If you want to use lambda:

```
>>> callstr2 = lambda x:eval(x)()
>>> callstr2("edithost")
Edit host
>>> callstr2("addhost")
Add host
```

Comment: eval doesn't allow to use the return value of the function.

Comment: I'm assuming he doesn't need to return anything.

Comment: If using eval [yech], it would be more clear to - `f = eval("addhost"); f()`. That is, rely on the fact that the function *is* a value. This observation also allows for approaches *without* eval - i.e. lookup-tables like dictionaries [yay] including globals/locals [yech], and other container objects (even modules) via attributes/properties [yay]

Comment: Thanks user2864740, I'm using your suggestion to improve my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I like jonrsharpe's idea and have used it before.  It's simple to code:

If you want to optimize things about, create the function dictionary outside of callit.

```
def fun1():
    return 1

def fun2():
    return 2

def nofun():
    raise ValueError('Unknown function')

def callit(funname):
    d = dict(fun1=fun1, fun2=fun2)
    fun = d.get(funname, nofun)
    return fun()

callit('fun1')
callit('badbadbad')
```

Answer (score -1):

I would lean towards the `getattr` method as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3071/3757019